# EclipseLink JPA Transaction.commit() does not return

Tags: java, jpa, persistence, jpa-2.0, eclipselink

I ran into a strange issue while using JPA (with EclipseLink 4.2.1).

The relevant part of the code:

```
l.debug("creating EM");
em = factory.createEntityManager();
int id = Integer.parseInt(idString);
l.debug("parsed");
em.getTransaction().begin();
SomeClass g = em.find(SomeClass.class, id);
l.debug("found");
em.remove(g);
l.debug("removed");
em.getTransaction().commit();
l.debug("Returning...");
```

The output is:

```
DEBUG - creating EM
DEBUG - parsed
DEBUG - found
DEBUG - removed
```

As you can see, the last row is not displayed (commit() did not return). It doesn't throw any exceptions. However, the object is removed from the database.

There is no such problem at any other point in the application.

Comment: A deadlock could be the root cause. Is anything else running at the same time?

Comment: Thanks Aksel, it looks like there was a deadlock indeed. I think I fixed it. If you could post that as an answer, I'd happy to accept it.

Comment: may you should look into using proper transaction isolation levels

Comment: Turn on Eclipselink logging to finest as this might show more on why it is hanging, and get a thread dump when it is noticed as this will show exactly where it is stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the root cause of hanging transactions can be a deadlock with other concurent transactions